# msvcbuild - how to compile luajit

Tags: lua, luajit

i'va just downloaded luajit and trying to compile it. i'm doing everything as it says [here](http://luajit.org/install.html)

to compile it i should execute msvcbuild from VS .NET Command Promt. so i installed VS 2010 and started VS 2010 Command Promt

and when i try to execute nsvcbuild it says "no such program and bla-bla-bla".

first i thought that there was no environment path. so i decided to find file msvcbuild.exe inside Program Files folder. and there is no such file.

what am i doing wrong and what should i do to compile luajit?

any help appriciated!

Comment: `msvcbuild.bat` is a batch script provided by luajit in the `./src` directory. It's not an executable. Try cd'ing into the src first before running it.

Answer (score 5):

Required steps to build using Visual Studio 2010:

1. open VS 2010 command prompt window
2. set up appropriate VS environment: e.g. **vcvarsall.bat x64** (for 64-bit) or **vcvarsall.bat x86** (for 32-bit)
3. go to luajit src directory: e.g. **cd \projects\luajit\src**
4. start the build: **msvcbuild.bat**

Comment: Another option is to run `msvcbuild.bat amalg`